# SUM and average weight PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sum, output, average

I'm working on something that calculates me total weight of my class and average weight of my class. In $T I entered weight of girls in class, in

```
Echo "SUM OF WHOLE CLASS IS : $s";
```

must be SUM of weight of whole class and

```
echo "<br/>AVERAGE WEIGHT IS $p";
```

is average weight of class.. I dont see where the problem is, it just says that is on line number 4..

```
 <body>
    <?PHP 
    $T=array (47,47,62,60,71,55,50,52,62,80,65);
    $s=0; $BUB=0; 
    for ($BUB=0;$BUB<=11;$BUB++)
    {
        $s=$s+$T[$BUB];
        $BUB++;
    }

    $p=$s/11;
    echo "SUM OF WHOLE CLASS IS : $s"; 
    echo "<br/>AVERAGE WEIGHT IS $p";

    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: See here: https://eval.in/98074 it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it simple using the `array` functions of PHP !

```
<?php
    $T=array (47,47,62,60,71,55,50,52,62,80,65);
    echo "SUM OF WHOLE CLASS IS : ".array_sum($T); //"prints the sum 
    echo "<br/>AVERAGE WEIGHT IS ".array_sum($T)/count($T); //"prints" the average
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/98075)

Comment: But i must have that it prints SUM OF WHOLE CLASS IS: and AVERAGE WEIGHT IS: this only prints numbers :/

Comment: @user3222689, Modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing that: `$BUB<=11` with `$BUB<11`.

Notice that `$BUB` start with the value 0. as well as the array. so `$T[11]` isn't exists.